# Pointer value Null in C

Tags: c, pointers, null

PointerName---Address---value
---------A--------- 1111------2222
---------B--------- 2222------3333
---------C--------- 3333------4444
---------D--------- 4444------stop

Here *A should be equal to B,
Here *B should be equal to C,
Here *C should be equal to D,
What should I put for value of D to indicate a stop of the list? Is putting 0 dangerous?

Comment: Please show a minimal compilable example.

Comment: You're not giving us the real story here. A pointer is a variable that contains one of two things: the address of some piece of memory, or the value NULL. What are you trying to do? Step back from the details a bit and give us the big picture.

Comment: As the question is currently shown, the second and third columns are both pointers, so the "stop" value should also be a pointer, namely NULL. Because your pointers point to other pointers, their "values" are pointers as well.

Answer (score 0):

`uintptr_t` is an integer type. It means "whatever size integer is big enough to hold the bits of a pointer". Therefore, if `p` points to something, `(uintptr_t *)(p)` is the same address pointing to an integer, and `GET(p)` is therefore the integer it points to.  `NULL` is a pointer type, so you're trying to assign that to an integer, which is not allowed.

Assigning it the value 0 would be allowed, but I'm not sure that's what you want, because you imply that you want to null a pointer, and assigning 0 would be making the pointer point to an integer 0, not changing the pointer itself.

I suspect that you don't really need all the casting at all, but you really just want to deal with pointers. But without seeing the rest of the code, there's no way for me to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: That doesn't help at all. What's a "WORD" (there's no such thing in C), and why do you think addresses belong in one? Addresses belong in pointers--that's what they are.

Comment: Here I assume the word size is memory address size.

Comment: Why do you assume that? If you want a memory address, use a pointer. If you want integer values, use integers. Don't mix them unless there's some vital reason to (like you want to store pointers in a structure written by someone else that only holds integers). "WORD" might mean anything, it's not part of the C language.

Comment: How do I know the size of the memory address? Is it sizeof(void *)? If a pointer is storing the address of the next pointer, in order to read the address, don't I have to decide how many bytes to read? Assume that I know the memory address length, how do I indicate that this pointer is no longer pointing to another address?

Comment: Why do you care about the size of an address? A pointer is a pointer, they just work. Step back from the trees here and give us some forest: what are you trying to accimplish? A linked list, or something?

Comment: A linked list without using any struct, directly manipulate the list in memory space.

Comment: Hmm. Then your "memory" would just be an array of `void **`? Not sure how meaningful it is to have pointers to pointers to nothing. Some actual code would go a long way here.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is usually defined as (void*)0 i.e. a pointer type of value 0.

Presumable you've got shorts (is that what you mean by WORD? i.e. 16-bit value) for A, B, C and D.

Therefore you need to assign a short to them.

The correct way of assigning a short is with a short value, not with a pointer, which is what NULL is.